# GAE AttributeError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, attributeerror

My GAE app runs fine from my computer, but when I upload it, I start getting an AttributeError, specifically:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item'
```

I am using the pylast interface (an API for last.fm--[link](http://code.google.com/p/pylast/)). Specifically, I am accessing a list of variables of this type:

```
SimilarItem = _namedtuple("SimilarItem", ["item", "match"])
```

I have a variable of this type, call it `sim`, and I am trying to access `sim.item` when I get the attribute error.

I should note that I am using Python 2.6 on my computer, and I understand that GAE runs on Python 2.5. Would that make a difference here? I thought they were backwards-compatible.

Lastly, I think it could be a possible problem with the modules that `pylast` imports--maybe they don't work with GAE or something? I did some research but I didn't get any results. Here are the imports:

```
import hashlib
import httplib
import urllib
import threading
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.dom
import time
import shelve
import tempfile
import sys
import htmlentitydefs
```

I would appreciate any help with this frustrating issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.5 doesn't have `namedtuple`.  It was added in 2.6.

**Edit:** It looks like the `_namedtuple` function is provided by `pylast` and will use a real `namedtuple` in Python 2.6+ but will fall back to a plain old `dict` in Python 2.5 or older.  That means that you'll have to use `sim['item']` or `sim.get('item')` when running in production.

Here's the source for that function:

```
def _namedtuple(name, children):
    """
        collections.namedtuple is available in (python >= 2.6)
    """

    v = sys.version_info
    if v[1] >= 6 and v[0] < 3:
        return collections.namedtuple(name, children)
    else:
        def fancydict(*args):
            d = {}
            i = 0
            for child in children:
                d[child.strip()] = args[i]
                i += 1
            return d

        return fancydict
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue entirely. Your response was very informative and helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, Python 2.6 is mostly **backwards**-compatible to 2.5 -- this means that what runs in 2.5 will mostly run in 2.6.  But you seem to misunderstand what **backwards** *means* -- it's the antonym of **forwards**, meaning that it's perfectly possible that what runs in 2.6 (if it uses new features that are in 2.6 but were not in 2.5) will **not** run in 2.5 (or previous versions).  Surely you see that the only way to avoid that would be to never, ever add **any** new features in new versions of Python -- a pretty dire remedy!-)

So I don't think you're well advised to use 2.6 for your local GAE development, since you know that 2.5 is what the production version will be using.  Why not download and install a Python 2.5 from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/) (or your linux distro's specific repos, if you're on Linux) and point your GAE SDK to use *that* version, instead of 2.6?  That would make your life substantially easier!

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding--I wasn't thinking through the issue clearly. I appreciate your response.